# WooCommerce product image span 2 columns with category filter

Tags: html, css, woocommerce

I need to apply a filter to allow me to increase the size of a specific product image for WooCommerce within my website www.warephotography.com.au.

The reason why I need to increase the product image size is because the photographs we sell are 3:1 ratio and display as small image for people to make a decision when purchasing. for example: 
http://www.warephotography.com.au/landscape-gallery/open-edition-prints/strong-and-courageous

The below CSS code allows the images to resize:

```
.woocommerce div.product div.images, .woocommerce #content div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page div.product div.images, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.images {
    width: 100%;
}
/* modify product summary width */
.woocommerce div.product div.summary, .woocommerce #content div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page div.product div.summary, .woocommerce-page #content div.product div.summary {
    width: 50%;
}
```

What I am stuck on is how I can filter this code to exclude specific product categories: 'vertical' & 'square'.

The reason why I  want to filter this is because of our vertical images. I don't want these to have 100% width and push the content way down the screen. For example:
http://www.warephotography.com.au/landscape-gallery/limited-edition-prints/sanctuary

Thanks in advance for the help and your time.